# Gast-lib - possible to activate speech recognition from Android home?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, activation

I found the gast-lib for Android, and I think is very interesting, specially for the part related to speech recognition and TTS.
I'm wondering about if it is possible to activate speech recognition from home screen of while using other applications, by saying keyword like "hello".
I tried in Android Sensing Playground app, by setting activation with movement. It works when the app is active, but not from home screen or from other apps.
Thanks for attention and help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is entirely possible.

Did you follow these steps in Android Sensing Playground?

1. Click "Activation Service Control"
2. Click "Movement"
3. Click back until you see the home screen
4. Shake the phone

This worked for me and I was able to trigger the service with movement from the home screen.

Comment: Yes you are right, it works perfectly also using speech activation. Want to test also if it works in differenti conditions band noisy environment.

Comment: I noticed that if you wait for a while after setting speech activation, then it doesn't work anymore. Any clue?